# C / C++: How to check an hardware Realtime Clock module battery status without root access?

Tags: c++, c, linux, real-time-clock

I'm building a "kiosk" app on a BeagleBone Black running Debian 10 using wxWidgets and c++.

I've installed a battery backed RTC module on it and using a DT overlay it runs fine.
*(It is an Adafruit PCF8523, but i'd like more to find a "generic" solution, as the kernel already handle it and i've seen the "low voltage" error in the journal)*

Now i need that my app

1. Check if the module is installed
2. Check the battery status

About 1. i thought that just getting the device name would be enough: everything different from the onboard one will mean that one RTC module is installed.
About 2. i don't have any idea: the producer shows some code using i2c communication but since the device is handled by his driver his i2c is busy. Also, i'd like to stay "generic", if possible.

I've searched and found a couple of code samples in the web to access the rtc and another possible problem occurred to me: they all access /dev/stc and so root permissions are required, which my app doesn't have.

So: how could i check the battery status of the module using C or C++  from a binary without root permissions?

## edit

As requested, the output of `cat /proc/driver/rtc`

```
rtc_time        : 11:59:37
rtc_date        : 2023-04-05
24hr            : yes
```

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /proc/driver/rtc` to your question.

Comment: Unfortunately `/proc/driver/rtc` doesn't show anything related to the battery. I asked because it is mentioned in https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1019914-start-0.html On a PC it shows a `batt_status` line. `/dev/rtc` might be problematic even as `root`, because AFAIK it can be opened only once. In https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/rtc.txt there is a reference to newer interfaces `/sys/class/rtc/rtcN` and `/proc/driver/rtc` but I don't know if these are supposed to provide the battery status.

Answer (score 1):

RTC driver of PCF8523 might have support for `ioctl` `RTC_VL_READ`.

By using that you can read related status bits from RTC:

```
#define RTC_VL_DATA_INVALID _BITUL(0) /* Voltage too low, RTC data is invalid */
#define RTC_VL_BACKUP_LOW   _BITUL(1) /* Backup voltage is low */
#define RTC_VL_BACKUP_EMPTY _BITUL(2) /* Backup empty or not present */
#define RTC_VL_ACCURACY_LOW _BITUL(3) /* Voltage is low, RTC accuracy is reduced */
#define RTC_VL_BACKUP_SWITCH    _BITUL(4) /* Backup switchover happened */
```

Non-root user requires at least access to the device file.

See source of [pcf8523_rtc_ioctl()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/pcf8523_rtc_ioctl) for more details.